# validateEmail REST Api call through Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript

I'm trying to validate an email in a cloud page using ampscript REST API Call but the httppost always returns me the 401 error.
I managed to call the accessToken just fine, but there is probably some error in my post, follows the code:

```
 SET @url = 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/address/v1/validateEmail/'

 SET @content = concat('{"Authorization":"Bearer ',@accessToken,'","email":"',@contactEmail,'","validators":','[ "SyntaxValidator", "MXValidator", "ListDetectiveValidator" ]}')

 SET @returnValid = HTTPPOST2(@url,"application/json",@content,@response)
```

Comment: I'd recommend building your REST call in Postman and then translating it to AMPscript once you've got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to put the Authorization/Bearer piece in slots 7 & 8 of the HTTPPOST2() function:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/httppost2.htm

```
SET @url = 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/address/v1/validateEmail/'

SET @content = concat('{"email":"',@contactEmail,'","validators":','[ "SyntaxValidator", "MXValidator", "ListDetectiveValidator" ]}')

SET @returnValid = HTTPPOST2(@url,"application/json",@content,true, @output,@respheader, 'Authorization', CONCAT('Bearer ', @accessToken))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It does make a lot of sense, and by downloading postman I noticed that I put the authorization on the body, which didn`t make any sense. Still, by using the code you provided the landing page won`t even load, not sure why, as soon as I remove the 4 and 5 slots in the httppost2 the page loads and gives me the 401 error again.

Comment: Hrm.... Let me actually test the code in my account.  The above code was just based on the documentation.

Comment: Figured out what I was doing wrong, I had to perform a null check on the @contactEmail variable before trying the httppost2.